# Multi-lingual dynamic contents using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, multilingual

I am developing a website using PHP and MySQL I used XML for static data to be able to create multilingual website the problem is with the other content in the database is it better to create a column for every language in each table or what?
and i am not using any template engine 
So i would like to know what are the good approaches to be able to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to add a `language` column to the database table(s). When new content is saved to the database, the language would have to be set. On the front end, you pull the content based on the language the user has selected.

```
SELECT * FROM ContentTable WHERE ContentID=<pageid> AND Language='en'
SELECT * FROM ContentTable WHERE ContentID=<pageid> AND Language='fr'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering that was really helpful. i have to wait 7 mins to accept the answer

Comment: No problem. This approach will be simpler if you need to add additional languages. Also, you may want to consider having a "default" language. So for example, if you have a content block that doesn't have an entry for some language, you can default back to English or something.

Comment: Thanks i will make sure there is a default language. That was a really good hint. you know i am still so new to PHP

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're gonna find the answer right here :

[Schema multi language database](http://fczaja.blogspot.be/2010/08/multilanguage-database-design.html)

Depend on the architecture of your website and other things.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

No, do not create a column per language - this is bad denormalization - you will have to alter tables for every new language.

Have a table with languages like this:

```
language_id, name, code
```

For example when you have a table `text_pages` it might look like this:

```
page_id, language_id, title, content
```

Then you have a row per language per page. Or you could have main table without `language_id` - the records there will be in the default language and second table `text_pages_ml` which holds `page_id, language_id, title, content` - only with other languages, translations! Then you can easily overwrite the main records with `LEFT JOIN`, in case the current language is different then the default language.

**Notice that the advantage in the second example** is that you could also have many columns that should not be translated! For example `author_id, date_created, date_updated`, etc - the `LEFT JOIN` will overwrite only those main fields that are translated and there will be no duplication of data that does not need translating!

There are many implementations but read about RDB Normalization and never consider the column per language per field design.

Comment: Thanks That was really helpful as well all the answers were amazing. and i wish i could accept them all.